# Reading user input with read back

Tags: bash, shell-script, freebsd

when I use simple bash command

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please, enter your name
read NAME
echo "Hi $NAME!"
```

and run it using `source filename.sh` it gives me an error `:Undefined variable`

what could be the problem? I search but there is no solution.

Comment: Does it run as expected when you invoke `./filename.sh` without `source`?

Comment: It gives me  "Permission denied"

Comment: Make the file executable by `chmod a+x ./filename.sh`, then run `./filename.sh` and post the result.

Comment: I did it, but it still not working : ./filename.sh: command not found

Comment: What shell do you use? (try `echo $SHELL`). What is the output of `/bin/bash -c ./filename.sh`?

Comment: I am working on Freebsd shell. and this is my first time using it. the output is     bin/csh

Comment: Do you have bash installed? If not use FreeBSD Ports to install it. Use `where bash` to find out.

Comment: Thank you so much. when I try `where bash` , it gives me `usr/local/bin/bash` . I change the `!/bin/bash` to `!/user/local/bin/bash` and it works fine. I can't thank all enough.

Comment: For the record: it works fine with `source filename.sh` or `./filename.sh` only?

Comment: @Loura : please accept the answer, if you do not know how to accept it [read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Summary for future reference:

The shebang points to `/bin/bash` but the `source` command makes the code run in a current shell which turned out to be `csh`.

The code works on my `bash` on Debian and it doesn't work on my `csh` there, when invoked with `source filename.sh`. Yet it looks like the OP's intention was to run it with `bash`.

To make it run with `bash` as intended, it needs to be made executable (`chmod a+x filename.sh`) and invoked by `./filename.sh`.

And finally the `#!/bin/bash` shebang had a wrong path in this particular case.

Comment: Note that the code would work in `csh` but do something different. Since `csh` has no `read` builtin, It would invoke a `read` command on the filesystem (which could not possibly set `csh`'s `$NAME` variable), The `echo "Hi $NAME!"` would work if $NAME was set as an environment variable on in `~/.cshrc` or anywhere else in the `csh` script prior to the `source`.

Comment: This is also fixes `... -p: no coprocess ... ` when trying to read user input and default and current shell is zsh